# How do I create a custom token in the Libra TestNet?

Tags: cryptocurrency, erc20, diem, move-lang

I want to create my custom token in Libra TestNet. I don't have much knowledge about the move programming language and need a lot of help. Is it possible to create our own implementation and execute in Libra Testnet?

What is sample implementation code? Please give some guidance on creating it.

Comment: Take a look to this: https://community.libra.org/t/implemented-basic-token-using-move-ir/526

Comment: Possible answer your question: [here](https://deqode.com/blog/move-language-tutorial/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had tried both the methods and the functional test failed with a parser error.